# magento image path [thoughts please]

Tags: magento

We host our Magento store internally with a not so amazing Internet connection.  It's good enough to process the shop, but images take a while to upload to the visitor.

So what we have done is tweak the image.php file in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model to point the images to a public space on RackSpace.

It's not an ideal method though with the admin console complaining that images don't exist and other random mess ups.

So I was wondering if anyone has implemented such a solution which I can use for our shop?

I imagine it will need to ignore the cache check as it cant upload to rackspace.

Comment: Why can you not use a CDN or move the site to an external host? I'm asking rhetorically so you might consider it yourself.

Comment: +1 for what @clockworkgeek said. Your situation is an issue for which CDNs exist. Really, though, a managed, Magento-tuned VPS is less than 100 USD/month if you are in the States, and I'm sure there are comparable offerings around the world.

Comment: My images are already on CDN with RackSpace, but to host a server online is quite expensive especially when Magento needs 2GB + to run smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the option of the backend of Magento
[image: Magento redirect images path]

And redirect the trafic of images to another server(CDN).
There is one more solution, for example the module of one pica CDN  with the option to select many CDN( amazon, custom cdn, etc) 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/onepica-imagecdn.html

Comment: that my friend, is a beautiful answer i so missed! thanks, shall give it a go.